# Query Builder inside entity - Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity, silex, query-builder

I'm looking to a better way to write this function.
It's inside a Doctrine Entity Model

```
public function getCompanySubscriptions()
{
    foreach ($this->subscriptions as $key => $value) {
        if ($value->getPlan()->getType() == 'E' && $value->getActive()) {
            return $value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

`$this->subscriptions` is a many-to-one collection and can have different "types" (but only one of them with type "E").

Problem is: If the `Company` has too many `$subscriptions` this function will be too slow to return that only one of type "E" which I need to check when  building the view with TWIG. The solution would be to use a `QueryBuilder`, but I haven't found a way to use it directly from the entity model.

Comment: Great blog post on this subject: https://www.boxuk.com/insight/blog-posts/filtering-associations-with-doctrine-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** use a `QueryBuilder` inside your entity, but instead you can use doctrine `Criteria` for filtering collections (on SQL level). Check the [documentation chapter **8.8. Filtering Collections** for more details on `Criteria`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections).

> If the collection has not been loaded from the database yet, the filtering API can work on the SQL level to make optimized access to large collections.

For example to only get active subscriptions:

```
$subscriptions = $this->getCompanySubscriptions();

$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("active", true));

$subscriptions = $subscriptions ->matching($criteria);
```

Like that you can solve your performance issues, since the collection is loaded from the database using the conditions from the `Criteria` directly.

The problem in your case might be that you need to join on `Plan`, but [joining is not possible in a `Criteria`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/2918). So if joining is really necessary then you should consider using a custom query where you do the join with conditions in your company `EntityRepository` (for example with a `QueryBuilder`).

**Note.**
The `foreach` in your question can be rewritten using [the `filter` method from the `ArrayCollection`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php#L298) class. The filter takes a predicate and all elements satisfying the predicate will be returned.
Look also [here in the doctrine 2 class documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html#_filter) for more info.

Your predicate would look something like:

```
$predicate = function($subscription){
    $subscription->getPlan()->getType() == 'E' && $subscription->getActive();
}
```

and then:

```
return $this->subscriptions->filter($predicate);
```